# nested delegate call of unknown type at compile time

Tags: c#, reflection

Supose I have a 2 Delegates, and i donw know the "TUnknown" type at compile time

```
  Func<T, TUnknown> delegate1;
  Func<TUnknown, object> delegate2;
```

how do I create a lambda statment like this:

```
(T t) => ((Func<TUnknown, object>)delegate2)(((Func<T, TUnknown>)delegate1)(t))
```

I was able to do it using DynamicInvoke like this:

```
(T t) => delegate2.DynamicInvoke(delegate1.DynamicInvoke(t));
```

But it is slow. There is a better solution ?

Full Code

```
static Func<T, object> PropertySerializerFactory(PropertyInfo property1)
{
    var delegate1 = property1.GetMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(property1.DeclaringType, property1.PropertyType));

    //Just a function that get a specific type of property
    //property2 is a property of the class property1
    PropertyInfo property2 = GetFilteredProperties(property1.PropertyType); 

    var delegate2 = property2.GetMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(property1.PropertyType, property2.PropertyType));

    return (T t) => delegate2.DynamicInvoke(delegate1.DynamicInvoke(t));
}
```

Comment: _Is it actually slow_ using `DynamicInvoke`? Did you do benchmarks, or did you just guess?

Comment: Surely `TUnknown` is a generic parameter? `object Foo<T,U>(Func<T,U> d1, Func<U,object> d2, T t) => d2(d1(t));` ?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Let's hope it's that easy. I was assuming that OP has the two delegates as `Delegate`. OP, please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Can't you do something like Func<T, object> composed = t => delegate2(delegate1(t)); ? (not sure what problem you are encountering)

Comment: @Sweeper, DynamicInvoke was 36x slower than Direct call. And Yes, the delegates are just "Delegate" types.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman, the problem is that i do now know the "U" parameter at compile time. most of the code is generated using reflection. So i Cant do a simple lambda.

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea, your statement does not compile to me. because i dont know the delegate parameters.

Comment: I will post the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways to solve this. First option, shift as much work as possible into a generic method;

```cs
static Func<T,object> GetFunc<T,U>(PropertyInfo prop1, PropertyInfo prop2){
    var getProp1 = property1.GetMethod.CreateDelegate<Func<T,U>>();
    var getProp2 = property2.GetMethod.CreateDelegate<Func<U,object>>();
    return (T t) => getProp2(getProp1(t));
}
```

Then once you know the runtime `Type`, you can make the correct generic version of your factory method and invoke it.

```cs
var method = typeof(...).GetMethod(nameof(GetFunc));
method = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[]{ type1, type2 });
return method.Invoke(null, new object[]{ prop1, prop2 });
```

The second option is to build an `Expression` tree and compile that instead.